# Setting up Pyspark with Ananonda

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I have a 4-node spark cluster. I have installed Anaconda 3.5 on all the nodes and the python installation location has been added to the PATH in all the nodes. However, when I try to run a pyspark application it looks like the Anaconda is not picked up properly and it gives me the following error message.

```
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 64, in main
("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.6 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions
```

$PATH on the driver and worker points to the Anaconda installation, however there is no other enviromental variable for pyspark or....

What is going on here?

p.s. my cluster is running RedHat.

Comment: Looks like PySpark is trying to be ran using python2

Comment: yes, but how can I make it to pick up the Anaconda installation which I have installed on all the nodes?

Comment: just for the record, it's also possible to install an Anaconda parcel via Cloudera Manager. That method auto-magically minds your configs, dependencies, etc.:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/02/making-python-on-apache-hadoop-easier-with-anaconda-and-cdh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your `$PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable? You can do this directly when running pyspark, though it might be easier to just fill-out all environment variables in your `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-env.sh`. For example, here's mine:

```
$ cat $SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-env.sh
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
```

See [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/configuration.html#environment-variables) for the full list of settings.

Comment: no I haven't, is it enough to just set it on the driver? or I have to do it on all the nodes?